# SLES 15 SP3 kernel version does not match release (/etc/os-release)

Tags: linux

I've upgraded from SLES 12sp5 to SLES 15sp3, using `zypper dup`. Seems to be upgraded, showing the kernel version of 15sp3, however `os-release` is still showing 12sp5.

```
uname -a

Linux EU-HWS-LNX192 5.3.18-57-default #1 SMP Wed Apr 28 10:54:41 UTC 2021 (ba3c2e9) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
cat /etc/os-release

NAME="SLES" VERSION="12-SP5" VERSION_ID="12.5" PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP5" ID="sles" ANSI_COLOR="0;32" CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:suse:sles:12:sp5"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what `rpm -V sles-release` shows?

Comment: # rpm -V sles-release
.......T.  c /etc/YaST2/control.xml
S.5....T.  c /etc/issue
S.5....T.  c /etc/issue.net
~ #

Comment: any one please help me out?